# Access kubernetes dashboard in ACS

Tags: azure-container-service

I've setup a kubernetes cluster using Windows containers on Azure Container Service and have successfully deployed my first replication controller.

I'd like to utilize the k8s dashboard as documented here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/

Navigating to the clusters DNS name via https with /ui appended to the path results in "Unauthorized". Same for the public IP of the cluster.

Then I tried "kubectl cluster-info" and it spits out a "kubernetes-dashboard" Url which is different than the above Url and also results in "Unauthorized".

Any ideas how I get this to work in ACS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented in the ACS documentation pages. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-ui

Comment: Argh, thank you Sir. I should have found that myself.